# Model suggestion: Keyword spotting

Tags: deep-learning, audio-processing, keyword-spotting

I want to predict the occurrences of the word "repeat" in a speech as well as the word's approximate duration. For this task, I'm planning to build a Deep Learning model. I've around 50 positive as well as 50 negative utterances (I couldn't collect more).

Initially I've searched for any pretrained models for keyword spotting, but I couldn't get a good one.

Then I tried **Speech Recognition** models (Deep Speech), but it couldn't predict the exact repeat words as my data follows *Indian* accent. Also, I've thought that going for ASR models for this task would be a over-killing one.

Now, I've split the entire audio into chunk of 1 secs with 50% overlapping and tried a binary **audio classification** in each chunk that is whether the chunk has the word "repeat" or not. For building the classification model, I calculated the MFCC features and build a sequence model on the top of it. Nothing seems to work for me.

If anyone already worked with this kind of task, please provide me with a correct method/resources to build a DL model for this task. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The binary classification using an RNN or CNN on MFCC data should work fine. What is your issue?

Comment: I'm suspecting whether the binary classification of one vs rest (here the word "repeat" vs all other words) will work or not in practice.

Comment: That is the standard setup when doing keyword spotting with a neural network. See works like https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07128v3

Comment: 50% overlap is quite small. I would go with maximum overlap, the hop length should be the same as the resolution of your MFCCs, something like 10-20 ms